# How to format text as code by indenting it

Tags: discussion

To enter code in StackOverflow, I indent each line with 4 spaces.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just add your code (without the spaces in front), then mark all your code and hit the code format button on top of the editor (or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>).

[image: illustration]

Comment: Thank you, I find select all my code, and hit ctrl + k, and indent multi line code.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use [Sublime text editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for editing small bits of code for stackoverflow, if you switch you indentation to four spaces and select all your code you can just add an extra indent to it all, like so:

[image]